# AWS Lambda TypeError: callback is not a function

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, twilio

I'm trying to make twilio access token in AWS lambda, but I get the error "callback is not a function". How can I fix it?

```
const AccessToken = require('twilio').jwt.AccessToken;
    const VoiceGrant = AccessToken.VoiceGrant;

    exports.generateToken = function(identity, callback) {
        // Used when generating any kind of tokens
        const accountSid = 'xxxxxxxxx';
        const apiKey = 'xxxxx';
        const apiSecret = 'xxx';

        // Used specifically for creating Voice tokens
        const pushCredSid = 'xxx';
        const outgoingApplicationSid = 'xxxxx';

        // Create an access token which we will sign and return to the client,
        // containing the grant we just created
        const voiceGrant = new VoiceGrant({
            outgoingApplicationSid: outgoingApplicationSid,
            pushCredentialSid: pushCredSid
        });

        // Create an access token which we will sign and return to the client,
        // containing the grant we just created
        const token = new AccessToken(accountSid, apiKey, apiSecret);
        token.addGrant(voiceGrant);
        token.identity = identity;
        console.log('Token:' + token.toJwt());
        callback(null, token.toJwt());
    };
```

Comment: Hey, This line `callback(null, token.toJwt());`? mh isn't the important part how you call `generateToken`?

Comment: @RolandStarke This is an important part, since here the result should return, I did two other lambda functions and they work well, but here I am constantly getting the error that I wrote above.

Comment: Mh could it be that AWS Lambda requires you to have 3 params? from the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_en/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html) `exports.myHandler = function(event, context, callback) {`

Comment: @RolandStarke No, there are not necessarily three parameters

Comment: Mh i meant you are required to use 3 params if you wanna use a callback. (but yeah ofc there could be some magic with parameter names. but in general there are no named parameters in javascript so i would give it a try to define your function with 3 params)

Comment: @RolandStarke you're right. if you want, you can formalize this as an answer and mark it as correct.

Comment: I am happy i could help. idk i never want to answer. but if you want you could delete your question. so noone else has to answer it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Roland Starke said, it's worth changing this `exports.generateToken = function(identity, callback)`  to `exports.generateToken = function(event, context, callback)` and everything will work fine.